# d3js how to scroll or tween properties

Tags: scroll, d3.js, tween

I have a div, #scrollable, with a scrollbar and I want to scroll to the end.
I can do it by setting the div's "scrollTop" property to the value of the div's "scrollHeight" property thus:

```
var scrollable = d3.select("#scrollable");
scrollable.property("scrollTop", scrollable.property("scrollHeight"));
```

but I can't figure out how, if at all, I can tween it.

```
var scrollheight = scrollable.property("scrollHeight");
d3.select("#scrollable").transition().property("scrollTop", scrollheight);
```

doesn't work.

Thanks for any ideas.
Regards

Answer (score 8):

You can use a custom [d3 tween](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-tween) to transition arbitrary properties like `scrollTop`.

mbostock's [Smooth Scrolling](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1649463) example demonstrates using a custom tween to scroll the entire document.

And here is the example adapted to your context (also [viewable interactively](http://bl.ocks.org/humbletim/5507619) on bl.ocks.org):

```
var scrollable = d3.select("#scrollable"); 

d3.select("#down").on('click', function() { 
    var scrollheight = scrollable.property("scrollHeight"); 
    d3.select("#scrollable").transition().duration(3000) 
        .tween("uniquetweenname", scrollTopTween(scrollheight)); 
}); 

function scrollTopTween(scrollTop) { 
    return function() { 
        var i = d3.interpolateNumber(this.scrollTop, scrollTop); 
        return function(t) { this.scrollTop = i(t); }; 
    }; 
}
```